# How do I split a large query with a semi-expensive function included into multiple smaller queries

Tags: wp-query, loop, recursive

I have a count stored in `post-meta` called `version-count`. I just wrote a little plugin to delete the data stored in this `post-meta` using `delete_post_meta_by_key`.

I want my plugin to then go through each post and re-run my `count-versions` function, which saves the new count in `post-meta`.

The problem is that when I run this code, I get a 504 error. My query returns 8,000+ results.

```
$args= array(
    'post_type' => 'release',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'release-format',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'album',
        ),
    ),
  );
  $newreleasequery= new WP_Query( $args );
  while ($newreleasequery->have_posts()) : $newreleasequery->the_post();
    $release_id=get_the_ID();
    get_album_version_count( $release_id );
    $count++;
  endwhile;
  echo 'All version counts have been reset. ', 'Count is ', $count;
```

There are too many posts in this query to run at once. How can I get it to piecemeal through the results and complete the function in chunks it can handle.

I'm guessing it has something to do with `posts_per_page`? Can I do something like this, and just keep writing more and more? It seems like there would be a faster/more efficient way to do this... Thanks all!

```
$args= array(
    'post_type' => 'release',
    'posts_per_page' => 250,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'release-format',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'album',
        ),
    ),
  );
  $newreleasequery= new WP_Query( $args );
  $querycount= $newreleasequery->found_posts;
  //echo $querycount;
  
  while ($newreleasequery->have_posts()) : $newreleasequery->the_post();
    $release_id=get_the_ID();
    get_album_version_count( $release_id );
    
  endwhile;
  wp_reset_query();
  if($querycount >= 250){
    $args= array(
        'post_type' => 'release',
        'posts_per_page' => 250,
        'offset' => 250,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'release-format',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'album',
            ),
        ),
    );
    $newreleasequery= new WP_Query( $args );
    $querycount= $newreleasequery->found_posts;
    //echo $querycount;
    
    while ($newreleasequery->have_posts()) : $newreleasequery->the_post();
        $release_id=get_the_ID();
        get_album_version_count( $release_id );
        
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();
  }if($querycount >= 500){
    $args= array(
        'post_type' => 'release',
        'posts_per_page' => 250,
        'offset' => 500,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'release-format',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'album',
            ),
        ),
    );
    $newreleasequery= new WP_Query( $args );
    $querycount= $newreleasequery->found_posts;
    //echo $querycount;
    
    while ($newreleasequery->have_posts()) : $newreleasequery->the_post();
        $release_id=get_the_ID();
        get_album_version_count( $release_id );
        
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();
  }
  
  echo 'All version counts have been reset. ', 'Count is ', $querycount;
```

Comment: If the post meta you are deleting holds the current count value, wouldn't it be cheaper and more efficient to extract the count and save it(in the new location) before deleting, rather than performing fresh and expensive lookups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using `'posts_per_page' => -1` is a bad practice as it loads every matching post from the database, which can mean hundreds, thousands or millions of entries in the worst case.

And it looks like you only need post ID's in your code, not the whole post objects. This means you can slim down the query by adding `'fields' => 'ids'` to the arguments to only retrieve the required post ID's.

In this case setting up the loop with `have_posts()` is also a bit unnecessary as the found posts can be accessed directly from the query object, e.g. `$query->posts`.

Instead of writing multiple queries and if statements, you can utilize a [`do-while`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php) loop with a paged query, which runs one or more times depending on how many pages of posts there are.

```
function wpse_410390_recount_versions_count() : void {
  $hasPosts = true;
  $paged = 0;
  
  do {
    $query = new WP_Query([
        'post_type' => 'release',
        'post_status' => ['publish', 'draft', 'future', 'private', 'pending'],
        'posts_per_page' => 100,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'tax_query' => array(
          array(
            'taxonomy' => 'release-format',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'album',
          ),
      ),
      'fields' => 'ids'
    ]);
  
    if ( $query->posts ) {
        foreach ( $query->posts as $post_id ) {
            some_function_to_update_versions_count($post_id);
        }
        $paged++;
    } else {
        $hasPosts = false;
    }
  } while ( $hasPosts );
}
```

Depending on your setup you might be able to toss in to the query arguments `'update_post_meta_cache' => false` and `'update_post_term_cache' => false` to slim down the query a bit more.

Comment: This is an excellent answer. Thanks so much.

Comment: Is it always faster to use a paged dowhile loop, rather than a `posts_per_page => -1` ?

Comment: @RCOTWUnite I don't think it is as much about speed as it is about memory usage. If you have under hundred or few hundred posts, then it probably doesn't matter which one you use. When you have thousands upon thousands of posts, then you'll most likely will end up crashing your site with "Out of memory" error, if you use `posts_per_page => -1`.

Comment: Thank you. I just started seeing that on one page, funnily enough. Thanks Antti, these are really helpful comments and answers.